# Obtener un historial del cambio de precio de un producto

Tags: oracle

Recientemente comencé a trabajar como desarrollador de base de datos; y me estanqué en una solicitud de un cliente.
Mi cliente quiere visualizar los cambios de precio de un producto o productos en cierto lapso de tiempo. El problema es que no sé como dividir la información o mostrar ambos precios en la misma fila.

Info que obtengo con mi consulta actualmente:

| Producto | precio_anterior | fecha_de_actualizacion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bolsa | $5.00 | 27-03-2022 |
| bolsa | $6.00 | 29-03-2022 |
| bolsa | $7.50 | 03-04-2022 |
| bolsa | $8.00 | 10-04-2022 |

Ejemplo de como debe mostrarse la info:

| Producto | precio_anterior | precio_actual | fecha_de_actualizacion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bolsa | $5.00 | $6.00 | 29-03-2022 |
| bolsa | $6.00 | $7.50 | 03-04-2022 |
| bolsa | $7.50 | $8.00 | 10-04-2022 |

Comment: Muestra la consulta que has intentado hasta el momento: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Esto se resuelve con la clausula OVER

Comment: Es difícil responder sin conocer la estructura de la(s) tabla(s) involucrada(s).